# jQuery: Access unique object contained within unique parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, containers, parent

Assume the following layout:

```
<span class="container">
    <video class="video">
        <source ... />
    </video>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="play">Play</div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Using jQuery I'm adding a click function on document load, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.playpause').click(function() {

        var play = $(this);
        var video = ''; // D:

    });

});
```

Assume there is no limit to the number of videos on the page or child parent objects of "controls". Meaning I don't want to use `$(this).parent().parent().find('.video')`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Maybe you're looking for `$(this).closest('.video')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [closest method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) seems like a good fit here

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.video');
```

Comment: The OP says there could be multiple ".video" in the ".container" element

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".video", $(this).parents(".container"))
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [prev() function](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous element, so this will work regardless of the number of video and/or controls elements inside the parent container...

```
var video = $(this).parent().prev();
```

breakdown...

`$(this)` gets the "play" class div

`.parent()` gets the "controls" class div

`.prev()` get the previous element (i.e. the matching "video" class div)

[here is a sample JS Fiddle to show the concept working](http://jsfiddle.net/X4hUn/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add an data element with the videos reference on the link:
    
        
            
        
        
            Play
        
    
Then

```
var video = $(this).data('ref');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var video = $('video', $(this).parentsUntil('span', '.container'));
```